# Determine all prime numbers that can be written as

Tags: prime-numbers

I have a question in this lesson:

"Determine all prime numbers that can be written as $ n^{2} - 1 $, for some $ n \in N $"

I tried to make $ n^{2} -1 = (n + 1) (n-1)$, but I didn't get any $n \in N $.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: $n = 2$????????

Answer (score 2):

If $n^2 - 1$ is prime, then at least one of $n+1$ and $n-1$ must be equal to $1$ (and it must be $n-1$ since that is the smaller of the two numbers).